# Unity Build failed with errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am new in unity and make my first ever game but when i try to build an apk 
It throws these 
**UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with errors.**
Here is the Pictures /Screen Shot of that error [image]

Comment: Have you clicked on "Reimport all assets" and tried again?

Comment: @RyanSingh  Yes Sir

Comment: @RyanSingh Any other solution ?

Comment: Have you tried to build in another folder or on your desktop?

Comment: Probably a corruption of some sort. Re-install unity. If it still fails after that, the the problem is with your project; probably either messed up folder structure or a script using some programming language feature that unity's Mono environment doesn't support.

Comment: @AlmightyR OK i will try actually my SDK version have also problem working o IT 
If i get solution i'lll share with you Sir thanks For your effort